# Probability of $m$ colors being chosen more than $r$ times out of $k$ colors

Tags: probability

I have $k$ colours, and I choose $n$ times, with replacement, from the $k$ colours. What is the probability that $m$ colours get picked more than $r$ times?

The probability that one colour is chosen $r$ times out of $n$ trials is given by the binomial distribution with uniform probability $1/k$. The probability that one colour is chosen more than $r$ times comes from summing the binomial distribution from $r$ to $n$. I do not know how to jump from there to answer the original question.

Thanks

Comment: "What is the probability that m colours get picked more than r times?" : Question, as posed, is ambiguous.  Index the colors $~c_1, c_2, \cdots, c_k,~: k \geq m.~$  Are you asking for the probability that the specific colors $~c_1, \cdots, c_m~$ each get picked more than $~r~$ times, which implies that $~m \times r \leq n~?~$  If this is not your intended question, what is?

Comment: @user2661923 I would agree that if $m \times (r+1) \gt n$ then the probability is $0$; similarly if $m> k$.  But I suspect that it can be any $m$ colours (from the original $k$) which are picked more than $r$ times.  I doubt there is an easy solution; for particular values simulation may give a reasonable approximation

Comment: I rephrase my question. You have k labels. You make n independent picks with reposition, what is the probability that m labels have each more than r picks? That is, each of the m labels was chosen more than r times. Of course k>m and r < n.

Comment: Should it be  given $m $ labels or arbitrary $m $ labels?

Comment: It should be arbitrary m labels

Comment: Is it then correct to formulate the problem as: "Find the probability that after $n$ trials there are at least $m$ colors, which were selected at least $r$ times." ?